# Solution to Problem in Introduction to Matematical Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2e^{-(x+y)}$ be a joint pdf for $X$ and $Y$ continuous random variables, defined for $0 \leq x \leq y, \ 0 \leq y$.
Please compute

> a) $P(Y < 1 | X < 1)$
>
> b) $P(Y < 1 | X =1)$
>
> c) $f_{Y|x}(y)$
>
> d) $E(Y| X = x):= E(Y|x) $

---

This is what I've done so far but something tells me the integrations bounds might be wrong.

a) $P(Y < 1 | X < 1) = \frac{P(Y<1, \ X<1)}{P(X<1)} = \frac{\int_0^1 \int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy}{\int_0^1f_X(x)dx}$ where $f_X(x) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy $. As @aaronmontgomery pointed out, then $f_X(x) = \int_x^\infty f_{X,Y}dy = 2e^{-2x}, 0 \leq x  \leq y$.

So now, the following results $f_X(x) = 2e^{-2x}$ and then $$P(Y < 1 | X < 1) = \ \frac{1-2e^{-1}+e^{-2}}{1-e^{-2}} = 0.4611...$$

b) $P(Y < 1 | X =1) = \int_1^1 \frac{f_{X,Y}(1,u)}{f_X(1)}du = (*)$, and again as it depends on previous calculations, if all is ok, that would be equal to $$ (*) = 0$$

c) $f_{Y|x}(y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ which would be $e^{x-y}$ for $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $y \geq 0$.

d) $E(Y|x) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} yf_{Y|x}(y)dy = \int_x^{\infty}ye^{x-y}dy = x+1$

Comment: On a), you say: "I've chosen $[0, \infty)$." Where have you chosen that? Are you referring to the calculation of $f_X(x)$?

Comment: Consider mentioning the support of the distributions whenever you write a pdf. And $E(Y\mid x)$ does not make sense. Either it is $E(Y\mid X=x)$ or $E(Y\mid X)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying @AaronMontgomery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) $P(Y < 1 | X < 1) = \frac{P(Y<1, \ X<1)}{P(X<1)} = \frac{\int_0^1 \int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy}{\int_0^1f_X(x)dx}$ where $f_X(x) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy $. In these integrals is where I'm having doubt about the bounds. I've chosen $[0, \infty)$. But I'm not sure.

One way to check whether you're on the right path is to see if you have constructed a valid density function. As you've defined it, you have $f_X(x) = \int_0^{\infty} 2e^{-(x+y)} \, \textrm{d} y = 2e^{-x}$, which should be valid on the support of $X$ -- that is, should be valid on $[0, \infty)$. However, you've got a problem; notice that $\int_0^{\infty} 2e^{-x} \, \textrm{d} x = 2$, not $1$ as it should be.

You're right to suspect an issue with your bounds. When you integrate out the $y$ variable, you need to take care to respect the relationship between $x$ and $y$; in particular, since we must have $x \leq y$, this should change your computation of $f_X(x)$ to
$$f_X(x) = \int_{\fbox{$\color{blue}{x}$}}^{\infty} 2e^{-(x+y)} \, \textrm{d} y$$
since $Y$ can never drop below $X$ (or, restated: the joint density is $0$ for $(x,y)$ pairs that have $y < x$). This will change your marginal density $f_X(x)$.

---

**EDIT** in response to edited question:

> So now, the following results $f_X(x) = 2e^{-2x}$ and then $$P(Y < 1 | X < 1) = \ \frac{1-2e^{-1}+e^{-2}}{1-e^{-2}} = 0.4611...$$

Looks good.

> b) $P(Y < 1 | X =1) = \int_{- \infty}^1 \frac{f_{X,Y}(1,u)}{f_X(1)}du = (*)$, and again as it depends on previous calculations, if all is ok, that would be equal to $$ (*) = e - 1 = 1.71828...$$

You can tell there's an issue here, because you've gotten something that's allegedly a probability, but is bigger than $1$. Once again, you need to take into account the relationship between $X$ and $Y$; since $X < Y$, if $X = 1$, what does that tell you about $Y$?

> c) $f_{Y|\color{red}{X}}(y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ which would be $e^{x-y}$ I don't know the support of this conditional pdf.

- If I tell you that $X = 7$, then $Y$ is supported on $[7, \infty)$.
- If I tell you that $X = 3$, then $Y$ is supported on... ?
- If I tell you that $X = x$, then $Y$ is supported on... ?

Your answers to those questions should inform where the density function is positive.

> d) $E(Y|\color{red}{X}) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} yf_{Y|\color{red}{X}}(y)dy = \int_?^?ye^{x-y}dy$ I need the support of the function.

Same answer as the previous part.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the new parts to your question.